# Is there equivalent to Illustrator "merge" function in other software?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, merge

I'm looking for same "merge" functionality (It's keeping all visible parts and discards overlaping (creates necessary nodes on shapes)) as in Illustrator in other (free) software / tool / scripts. I would like to use it for bulk of 10k files so if there is command-line options it will be best.   [image: functionality of "merge" tool]

Comment: What is a <10k file? Weight?

Comment: @Rafael - **OP** says *"... for <10K file..."* and given their preference for command-line options, I ***think*** they mean *"...use for batch processing a <10k count of files..."* but the ***OP*** would need to clarify if I'm correct.

Comment: What does the merge functionality in Illustrator do? You can group multiple shapes in Inkscape, which allows to move them in one go, resize, rotate and so on, but it looks, as if Illustrator would add nodes to intersection points.

Comment: It looks as if it's keeping the parts of the shapes that are visible, and discards the rest. Inkscape does not have such functionality - not by default, and not with any user-contributed Inkscape extension I have ever seen.
Trace Bitmap would provide a similar functionality, if you uncheck 'stack scans' and use 'Multiple scans: colors' for tracing a bitmap copy.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - 10k is count of files I need to process with this function. It is not necessary to be command-line (it will be best though) but I can write some macro - just need something outside Adobe ;)

Comment: add functionality - Moini described it exactly - It's keeping all visible parts and discards overlaping (creates necessary nodes on shapes)..

Comment: It can be done in other software like Inkscape, but not in one operation - however I wouldn't recommend it - unless you are merging images like that for a laser cutter or something like that.  It adds extra anchors/nodes, and will therefore increase the file sizes.

Comment: It would probably be possible to modify inx-pathops, so it can do this: https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-pathops

Comment: The file size or number of nodes is not a issue. Source data is quite simple.. 
I tried do "merge" in Inkscape but I cannot figure out some universal chain of commands to correct result.

Comment: Take the topmost object, and subtract it from all objects below. Repeat with the next object below the topmost object, etc. until you reach the bottom of the stack. The inx-pathops extension will make this a lot faster, as it can do multiple difference and has an option to keep the subtracted object. Oh, and this will only work with objects that are completely opaque, it's not going to work if you want to preserve  mixed colors.

Comment: Thanks Moini - with keeping substracted object I think it could work.. (have to do some test), anyway shame that there is no straight way like illustrator "merge"..

Comment: Here in GDSE one common repeated question has been "How can I remove one pixel wide light stripes from the seams between facing objects?" You probably are just now asking a method to generate those stripes to 10k files. They appear when the all-merged (=no overlaps) file is converted to SVG or PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Object -> Group in Inksacpe has been mentioned but an alternative worth knowing about is Path-> Combine -it has a caveat that that you only work with paths - so not gradients, clones etc. It's also extremely useful for getting round Inkscape's 2 object limit for most of its path tools, filters and extensions.

Why you would use either depends on what you want to gather together and why.

Object -> Group will make a composite object without altering ordering, fill colour, stroke weight or individual effects. You can also use the Object Properties browser to selectively hide elements and Selection Sets to make accessing individual elements within a group much easier.

For the example you posted, using grouping, the end result will be an object that looks like your final image.

Path -> Combine will allow Inkscape to treat various paths them as 1 path object with the colour and stroke weight being set to that of the topmost path object. It will allow you to use a single path subtraction to cut the hexagon into all 3 shapes.

If you are dealing with a lot of objects and you want them to keep their individual fill, stoke and so on, then groups are the way to go. If the negative space of a shape interacting with other shapes is what you want then use the pathing tools. Though you will have to repeat the intersection with each object if you want them to retain their fill colour etc.

For dealing with the 10k files, and double guessing what you want to do with them, you can run Inkscape from the command line and assuming your dealing with SVG, Inkscape will turn the import into a group maintaining the original positioning, z order and so on of the original file.

So start by making a document that will be the container for all your files

-> create a new document

then again from the command  line

-> FileOpen /the/file/you/just/made
-> FileImport 
-> FileSave

if you put a programming loop around this (in whatever language you prefer - java, python, perl, ruby) that counts up to 10k or however many files you have, it will store them in the same document.

If they are .ai files, as I recall Inkscape will correctly handle anything that is standard SVG, however if you have used Illustrator internals like symbols and gradient meshes, you'll need to change these to something non propriatry before hand - export them as svg from Illustrator first.

More info on [the commands](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_use_Inkscape_in_commandline_mode/List_of_verbs) available for Inkscape

Comment: Group or Combine is far from result I want to achieve. Combine puts all shapes together without respecting colors and inner shapes..

Comment: the issue is it's not clear what you are actually asking for advice on. If you are looking for a way of making a composite object regardless of what it contains then Group is what you want - it doesn't alter anything. Combine despite it's name will not alter path objects, it will allow you to use filters on multiple paths

Comment: @Destrosvet why dont you record an action in illustrator and run that on your files. Yeah it's slow but then again you'd be done by now. And yes there is no really good high order programming interface for vector operations.

Comment: You can script Inkscape pretty well from the command line and as it runs without all the graphical overhead it is surprisingly fast. However without a clearer explanation of what the OP wants it's hard to deal in specifics.

Comment: Sorry for lack explanation - I wrongly assumed that Illustrator "merge" is widely known. => I'm going to do animation ;)

Comment: Can I suggest you change your question so it explains what you want.